# Java group policy install succeeds but not fully installing

Tags: group-policy, java, msi, windows-installer

I am attempting to deploy java over group policy and am running into a few issues. Sometimes when the msi installs, the installer reports that it succeeded in the event viewer, but when I go to the java directory, I do not see the bin folder or any other folders that would indicate it installed successfully. Here is an image of what I am talking about (it's for jdk but jre has the same issue as well).

[Picture of failed install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO83L.png)

I have noticed this happens when the msi attempts to install over a previous version of java (When the computers were setup, java was installed manually, I now want to do this over group policy).

Has anyone experienced this and can tell me what's going wrong? I assume the java msi can't handle upgrading over a previous installation but am unsure on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out java doesn't support reinstall through the msi as is seen in this [Bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6947907). I wish the java msi would just not touch anything if it saw it needed to do a re-installation, but oh well.